# DataGridView CellContent Checkbox Change Event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview with 3 columns: invoice id, price and a checkbox.

If checkbox is clicked price becomes 0 for that row. Now that is happening.

But when I uncheck the checkbox price should be as it was. But it is remaining zero. Below is my code for cellcontent click. How can i get previous price if checkbox in unchecked?

```
private void grvItems_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
    DataGridViewRow row = this.grvItems.CurrentRow;
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn &&
             e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == grvItems.Columns["UnderWarranty"].Index)
            {
                string returnAmt = lblReturnAmountVal.Text;
                bool isCheked = (bool)grvItems.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["UnderWarranty"].EditedFormattedValue;

                if (isCheked)
                {
                    grvItems.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PRICE"].Value = "0.00";
                    lblReturnAmountVal.Text = "0.00";
                }
                else
                { 

                }
                grvItems.EndEdit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the CheckedChanged event? On Winforms and using checkboxes that should help. Untested code below:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (checkBox1.Checked)
     {
         value = 0;
     }
     else
     {
         // whatever other logic should happen
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert to the original data value you will need to **store** it somewhere.

You can always use the cell's `Tag` property for this:

```
             DataGridViewCell cell = grvItems.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PRICE"];
            if (isCheked)
            {
                cell.Tag = cell.Value;
                cell.Value = "0.00";
                lblReturnAmountVal.Text = "0.00";
            }
            else
            { 
                //            use your cell's datatype here!!  VVV
                if (cell.Tag != null) cell.Value = cell.Tag as decimal;
            }
```